# Incorrect Predictions from Tensorflow Spelling Correction Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I trained a Tensorflow model for spelling correction. I trained for >60 epochs and achieved an accuracy of ~82.2% with a loss of 0.3032. When I try to make predictions with the model, it didn't provide any correct predictions. The model is trained with >100k sentences of which about 20% have spelling errors. The output is binary data (not one-hot encoded). The model didn't provide correct predictions even with some of the training data. The model is as follows:

```
def create_model():

  tf.random.set_seed(42)

  # input_layer = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],1),name='input_layer')#input layer for use without embedding
  input_layer = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1]),name='input_layer')#input layer for use with embedding
  sp_embedding_layer = Embedding(len(char2idx),EMBEDDING_DIM,embeddings_initializer=initializers.Constant(embed_matrix),trainable=False)(input_layer)#embeddings_initializer=initializers.Constant(embed_matrix),

  x = Bidirectional(LSTM(1024,return_sequences = False))(sp_embedding_layer)
  x = Dense(1920, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_1')(x)
  x = Dense(2048, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_2')(x)
  x = Dense(2048, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_3')(x)
  x = Dense(2048, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_4')(x)
  x = Dense(2048, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_5')(x)
  x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_6')(x)
  x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu',name='Dense_7')(x)
  x = Dense(y_train.shape[1],name='Output',activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
  model = models.Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = x)

  return model
```

Optimiser and callbacks are as follows:

```
sf = 4

spb = x_train.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE #steps per batch
sf_epoch = spb * sf


myoptimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000001)


filepath="/content/drive/MyDrive/NLP/Models/SCModels/weights.{epoch:02d}.tf"
checkpoint = EpochModelCheckpoint(filepath,frequency=sf,save_weights_only=True)
# ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
#                              mode='max',save_freq = sf)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,verbose=1,
                              patience=2)

callbacks_list = [checkpoint,reduce_lr]
```

Training code:

```
history = n_model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_val,y_val),epochs=60,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

The prediction code is as follows:

```
test_model = create_model()
test_model.load_weights(selected_model)
test_optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0983)
test_model.compile(optimizer=test_optimizer,loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('input:',sample_sent)
input = np.array(encode(sample_sent,MAX_SENT_LEN+10)).reshape((1,-1))
answer = test_model.predict(input)
answer_dec = np.where(answer<0.5,0,1)
print(answer_dec[0].tolist())
print(decode(recover_int_seq(answer_dec[0].tolist())))
```

Why are the predictions off? I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the code where you fit the model. If the training is not expensive I suggest you also use a validation set for every epoch and see how the validation loss and accuracy change. Also why are you re-compiling the model after loading the weights?

Comment: The stack of high dimensional Dense layers looks like place where overfitting can easily happen. Many parameters and no Dropouts.

Comment: I've added the 'fit' line.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you do not really need so many Dense layers. Think of adding LayerNormalization and Dropout layers instead of some Dense layers.